# How to fix curl_exec call hanging when Xdebug is enabled

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, ddev

I have a local [ddev](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (docker based) **PHP Drupal 7** development environment set up. I have set up **Behat** tests for this site utilizing the [Behat Drupal Extension](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalextension).

All of the Behat context files and the associated composer vendor folder lives outside of the site's web root in a testing folder. The folder structure looks something like:

- Project

  - testing
  - public_html

I have **xdebug** enabled and using **PhpStorm**. I have set up a PhpStorm debug server and provided correct path mappings.

Debugging php code via a browser works great, debugging **CLI** commands works great. My issue occurs when I try to debug all code while running Behat tests via the CLI.

In the PhpStorm PHP Server configuration if I only set the path mappings for the `testing` folder I can debug any code within the testing folder and there are no curl issues. I obviously can't debug code in the `public_html` folder because I have not set the path mappings. When I do set the path mappings for both the `testing` and `public_html` folders, I can debug all code but any behat step definition that includes a Mink `curl_exec()` call to the site's local url, hangs for anywhere from 3 to 10 minutes!

**My goal...**

To be able to debug all php code in the `testing` and `public_html` folders while running Behat tests without `curl_exec()` hanging.

**What I have tried...**

I have PhpStorm Debug Max Simultaneous Connections set to 10 and have tried 20.

Here are my xdebug remote config settings:

```
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => host.docker.internal => host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
```

All of the following have all resulted in curl hanging:

- Set `xdebug.remote_autostart=0` and started the Xdebug session by passing a `XDEBUG_CONFIG=idekey=PHPSTORM` environment variable in with my behat command AND

  - NOT passing any cookie or **GET** parameter with the curl call.
  - Passing the same **idekey** as a cookie and GET parameter with the curl call
  - Passing a different idekey as a cookie and GET parameter with the curl call

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Collect Xdebug log, it may say what is going on (if it tries to connect and where). `xdebug.remote_log`

Comment: Is this only happening when you try to access a URL from the same application?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @LazyOne and NicoHaase. Yes the issue is only happening when a URL from the same application.  I collected Xdebug logs and they revealed that the connection was being made and getting stuck on a Run command. This lead me to think it was something PhpStorm specific or the site not responding that was causing the issue. I have detailed more in my answer below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

After following @LazyOne advice I looked at the Xdebug logs more closely and noticed the hanging was occurring after a successful xDebug connection was made. This lead me to two possible causes; some rouge breakpoint that was not getting registered in the PhpStorm Debug tool window or something on the site was delaying the response.

So I did the following:

1. Removed all PhpStorm Debug breakpoints in the application and restarted PhpStorm.
2. Realized the Automatic Cron setting in Drupal 7 Configuration was set to run every `1 Day` so switched it to `Never`. My thinking was possibly the execution of Drupal Cron was getting stuck and not completing so every HTTP request was hanging.

It worked and now I wish I had tested each of these steps separately because I don't know which one exactly was the solution. I am leaning towards #1 because when I switched off debugging in PhpStorm the Behat test would execute with no delay. Either way, if you have a similar issue try both of the above.